# Colorbox and Ajax.ActionLink not working well together

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, colorbox

When I attempt to get my actionlink to call the colorbox to open it keeps returning "colorbox is not a function"

```
    @Html.DropDownList("JobTypeId", String.Empty) | @Ajax.ActionLink("Add Job Type", "AddJobType",
                                                               new AjaxOptions
                                                               {
                                                                   UpdateTargetId = "inline_form",
                                                                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                                                   HttpMethod = "GET", 
                                                                   OnSuccess = "openbox();"
                                                               })
```

//in header

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.colorbox-min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function openbox() {
            $.colorbox({ width: "50%", inline: true, href: "#inline_form" });
        }
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: do  you include jQuery as well ? (***before** including the `jquery.colorbox-min.js`*)

Comment: @gaby Yes, it's in the _Layout.cshtml

Comment: Would be better to just use jQuery and not MSAjax, if you inform me what it is exactly you are trying to do I will help you write it

Comment: I'll also add that the html is getting updated by the ajax call.

Comment: And it gets crazier.  When I add a static link to the page to view the hidden html... yes, it works.